# SORLJ undefined field null

Tags: solr

I am trying to make simple readings over Lucene indexes by using SolrJ. I have been able to access the sample index available in the SolrJ download, but I get an exception when trying to make the reading.

```
04-feb-2010 17:05:05 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
              GRAVE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field null
```

My index only has one document with a single field, called “nombre”

I have specified this in the schema.xml and the route in the slconfig.xml

Java code

```
System.setProperty( "solr.solr.home", "C:\\solr" );

// CREATING THE SERVER  
CoreContainer.Initializer initializer = new CoreContainer.Initializer();
CoreContainer coreContainer = null;
SolrServer embServer = null;
coreContainer = initializer.initialize();
embServer = new EmbeddedSolrServer(coreContainer, "");

// READING
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
String q = "*";
query.setQuery(q);
QueryResponse rsp = null;

/// HERE I GET THE EXCEPTION ///
rsp = embServer.query( query );
/// HERE I GET THE EXCEPTION ///

// GETTING THE NUMBER OF ITEMS
SolrDocumentList docs = rsp.getResults();
System.out.println( docs.size() );
```

Any ideas? Can you give me a solution? Is it a common mistake? Thank you very much in advance.

---

**If I try this with the Jetty admin console I get :
(url: "http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*")**

HTTP ERROR: 400

undefined field null

RequestURI=/solr/select/

**The shema.xml is this one:**

(Remember my index only has one document with a single field, called “nombre” )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="example" version="1.2">
  <types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
  </types>
<fields>
<field name="nombre" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</fields>
</schema>
```

**The solrconfig.xml is this one:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <config>
   <requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" />
   <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:./data/clientes}</dataDir>
 </config>
```

**The exception I am getting is:**

05-feb-2010 10:07:11 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
GRAVE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field null
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1136)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1098)
       at org.apache.solr.search.SolrQueryParser.getWildcardQuery(SolrQueryParser.java:193)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:1434)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:1337)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:1265)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:1254)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:200)
    at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParserPlugin.java:78)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:131)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:89)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:174)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1316)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer.request(EmbeddedSolrServer.java:139)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:89)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:118)
    at paqueteBase.PruebaDeSolr.ejecutate(PruebaDeSolr.java:67)
    at paqueteBase.PruebaDeSolr.main(PruebaDeSolr.java:24)

Comment: Hi.. what's the exception you're getting?

Comment: the query should be "*:*" instead of "*" but I don't think that's what causing the exception... can you post your schema.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems I needed to specify the field "nombre" as uniqueKey and defaultSearchField in the schema.xml. It is starting to work.

Answer (score 1):

In your q parameter there's a wrong query string, should be *:* and not only *. You are getting that exception because SOLR is trying to resolve the name of the target field, first trying with declared field and then looking for a dynamic field definition.